# How to make my program take other line of numbers from data.txt file

Tags: c++

So i am pretty new in C++, and i've been trying to make couple of programs, but im facing the same problem in both of them. Program needs to open data.txt file, read how many lines of numbers there are, then read first line of numbers, use those numbers for for few formulas, then write them into seperate file. So far i've made this, the program calculates correctly, but the problem is that the program only takes first line of numbers, and repeats using them ( doesnt go for second line). Please help me figure out how to make it work properly.
This is the code what i have made so far:

```
Data.txt contains:
2
2 5
3 7
--------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//Const chars
const char FVD[] = "Data.txt";
const char FVR[] = "Result.txt";

 //Function prototypes
void Input (const char FV[], double &a, double &b, double &n);
void Output (const char FV[], double &a, double &b, double &S, double &P);
double Area (double &a, double &b);
double Perimeter (double &a, double &b);


int main()
{
    double a,b,S,P,n;
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    Input(FVD,a,b,n,S,P);
    S=Area(a,b);
    P=Perimeter(a,b);
    Output(FVR,a,b,S,P);
    }

    return 0;
}
//Functions:

//Area:
double Area (double &a, double &b)
{
return a*b;
}
//Perimeter:
double Perimeter(double &a, double &b)
{
double P=(a*2)+(b*2);
return P;
}
// Input:
void Input (const char FV[], double &a, double &b, double &n)
{
    ifstream D(FV);
    D >> n;
    D >> a >> b;
    D.close();
}
 // Output
void Output (const char FV[],double &a, double &b, double &S, double &P){
    ofstream R(FV);
    R << a << setw(4) << b << setw(4) << S << setw(4) << P;
    R << endl;
    R.close();
}


Result in Result.txt
2 5 10 14
```

EDIT: Same result with D.close(); and R.close(); functions outside the loop:

```
int main()
{
    double a,b,S,P,n;
    ifstream D(FVD);
    ofstream R(FVR);
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
      Input(FVD,a,b,n);
      S=Area(a,b);
      P=Perimeter(a,b);
      Output(FVR,a,b,S,P);
    }
    D.close();
    R.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Input and output functions:

```
void Input (const char FV[], double &a, double &b, double &n)
{
    ifstream D(FVD);
    D >> n;
    D >> a >> b;
}

void Output (const char FV[],double &a, double &b, double &S, double &P){
    ofstream R(FVR);
    R << a << setw(4) << b << setw(4) << S << setw(4) << P;
    R << endl;

}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang), and pay attention to them.

Comment: You're opening reading the 1st line, and closing  your file every time when calling `Input() `. You should rather have a loop, that reads all lines from the file.

Comment: Even though i made D.close(); and R.close() in the end of the loop ( removed these two from input and output functions) it still gives me the same result

Comment: By the way, for future reference try to create a [mininal, complete, and verifiable] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. In this case I think after your edit it was a good example of what minimal should be. The other code wasn't necessary. Plus one for your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the Input function. You're opening and closing the file every time, so that's causing it to read the same first line over and over again. You want to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    double a,b,S,P,n;
    ifstream D(FV);
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
      Input(D,a,b,n,S,P);
      // other stuff
    }
    D.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Your input function just like this:

```
void Input (const ifstream D, double &a, double &b, double &n)
{
    D >> n;
    D >> a >> b;
}
```

And just fyi, you are probably going to run into the same problem with your output function. I hope this helps, good luck!

**Edit** Declare D outside the loop in main, and pass it as a param to Input

**Second Edit** Here is a working example (just copy paste):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//Const chars
const char FVD[] = "Data.txt";
const char FVR[] = "Result.txt";

 //Function prototypes
void Input (ifstream & D, double &a, double &b);
void Output (ofstream & R, double &a, double &b, double &S, double &P);
double Area (double &a, double &b);
double Perimeter (double &a, double &b);


int main()
{
    double a,b,S,P;
    ofstream R(FVR);
    ifstream D(FVD);

    // The value of n was a problem for two reasons
    // One it was declared as a double when it was trying to get an int (2)
    // Two it was getting read more than once
    int n;
    D >> n;
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    Input(D,a,b);
    S=Area(a,b);
    P=Perimeter(a,b);
    Output(R,a,b,S,P);
    }
    D.close();
    R.close();

    return 0;
}
//Functions:

//Area:
double Area (double &a, double &b)
{
return a*b;
}
//Perimeter:
double Perimeter(double &a, double &b)
{
double P=(a*2)+(b*2);
return P;
}
// Input:
void Input (ifstream & D, double &a, double &b)
{
    D >> a >> b;
}
 // Output
void Output (ofstream & R,double &a, double &b, double &S, double &P){
    R << a << setw(4) << b << setw(4) << S << setw(4) << P;
    R << endl;
}
```

Comment: `D` isn't accessible in the scope of `Input()`.

Comment: I just tried that. Changed my input and output, int main() stuff's, still getting same result

Comment: @Emilis you're probably still opening inside the loop aren't you? If you open inside the loop it will happen every time even if it's in main or in a function

Comment: I just edited the post. I am kinda lost right now. Do i need to make it read n value seperately, then make for () loop and inside it i should read the a and b values?

Comment: Your new edit looks almost right, except that you're still declaring a new ifstream/ofstream inside your functions. I edited my answer. You should send D, and R as params

Comment: "const D ifstream" is giving me an error: 'D' does not name a type.
Tried changing: void Input (const char FV[], double &a, double &b, double &n)
into: void Input (const D ifstream, double &a, double &b, double &n);

Comment: Well that would be because I had a typo haha, the function signature should be:
const ifstream D, my bad...

Comment: I'll be out, but it looks to me that your declarations are empty they should look like this: `ifstream D(FVD)` as oppose to this: `ifstream D`

Comment: Should i change that in int main() only, or in void parameters too?

Comment: just in main. Look at my answer, I think it should have everything you need

Comment: Now i am getting this: error: use of deleted function

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ms9run Basically im getting more and more errors as i go further hahah

Comment: I'll build a running example once I'm on my computer

Comment: Sorry I took a while I wasn't at my computer earlier today. I got that working on my machine. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Oh my! It works perfectly! Thank you so much! I was curious to ask: Does "ifstream & D" works the same way as for example "double &a" ? Just trying to understand what i should do differently in the future.

Comment: Yes it does. Ifstream itself is a variable, and contains the current character being read (see function peek) among other things. Read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) for more information